# Picasso Only Loading 5 Images until re-using ones in cache

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, picasso

I'm fairly new to android programming. I've run into some issues loading images (bitmaps) into  a ListView. It works flawlessly until I have around 5 images loaded, then it reuses the first image I loaded (assuming from cache). I've tried a lot of solutions and bitmap samplings but, still no luck. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);

            name.setText(currentContact.getName());
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
            TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
            email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
            address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());

            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

            File file = mContext.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String path = "file:" + file.getPath() + "/" + currentContact.getImage() + ".png";

            ImageView contactListImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactListImage);

              Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())      
                        .load(path)
                        .centerInside()
                        .fit()
                        .error(R.drawable.user_2)
                        .into(contactListImage)
        }
        return view;
    }
```

I did try using

```
recycleMemoryCache()
```

Thank in you advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the recycled view correctly.

The `view` parameter you have there is either null, which means you have to inflate a new one, or *not* null, which means you should *re-use* it - assign new values to all the fields etc.

You simply need to move the closing curly-brace above `return view;` to just after your view inflation:

```
if (view == null) {
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
}
```

As an aside, I'd look up the viewholder pattern - or just start using RecyclerView, as that enforces it (and is the way of the future for lists on Android).

Comment: Wow can't believe the solution was so simple. Works wonderfully now. Thanks!